# Cypress Uncaught Assertion Error despite cy.on('uncaught:exception')

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception

In relation to the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error.
Cypress detected that an uncaught error was thrown from a cross origin script.
We cannot provide you the stack trace, line number, or file where this error occurred.
```

Referencing https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#To-catch-a-single-uncaught-exception

I am trying to run a test that fills out a form and clicks the button to submit:

```
it('adds biological sample with maximal input', function(){
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    expect(err.message).to.include('of undefined')
      done()
      return false
    });
    cy.get('a').contains('Add biological sample').click();

 . . . 

    cy.contains('Action results');
  });
```

I get an error despite my spec containing the following:

```
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    expect(err.message).to.include('of undefined')
      done()
      return false
    });
```

Here's an image of the test failing [image: the test failing].

The error in the bottom left reads,

> Error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected  '$f is not defined\n\nThis
>   error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.
>   \n\nWhen Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your
>   application it will automatically fail the current test.\n\nThis
>   behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by
>   listening to the \'uncaught:exception\'
>   event.\n\nhttps://on.cypress.io/uncaught-exception-from-application'
>   to include 'of undefined'
>   (https://www.flukebook.org/_cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:49186)

It seems that I am taking Cypress's advice and not getting the desired result. Any suggestions? Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: My guess is that `cy.on('uncaught:exception',` is not handling it because `AssertionError` is a different underlying type to `Exception`. You could raise this as an issue with Cypress, or try to trap it in another way (not sure if that's possible). However, the developers have added an assertion for a reason. A better path would be to find out why and test accordingly, and / or ask then to change the code that raises the error from an Assertion to an Exception.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm running into the same one. Our issue is described here, but there's no workaround/solution for it..

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/987#

Comment: His code was catching the AssertionError correctly but failing because he was asserting that the text "of undefined" is present in the text of the AssertionError, which it is not...  If he had written "is not defined" instead then it would pass.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Can you please remove `expect(err.message).to.include('of undefined')` and `done()` from the cypress exception block and add the below piece of code inside the test & run the test again

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
    return false
})
```

Comment: Can you please try printing just the cy.contains(“Actions results”); part alone to console.log () and see if there are not any special or unfamiliar characters

Comment: Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way to fix this is to add the following to the top of your spec:

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false;
});
```

This gets the same indentation level as your "it" blocks, nested directly under "describe".  It will cause cypress to ignore all uncaught JS exceptions.

In the question, Atticus29 expects "of undefined" to be present in the error message, but the error doesn't actually contain that string.  He could change

```
expect(err.message).to.include('of undefined')
```

to

```
expect(err.message).to.include('is not defined')
```

then it will pass.

**To turn off all uncaught exception handling in a spec** (recommended)
https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#To-turn-off-all-uncaught-exception-handling

**To catch a single uncaught exception and assert that it contains a string**
https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#To-catch-a-single-uncaught-exception

Answer (score 3):

Although the fix of suppressing `Cypress.on` sometimes fix the problem, it doesn't really reveal the root problem. It's still better to figure out why you are having an unhandled error in your code (even in the test).

In my case, my form submission forward the page to another page (or current page), which causes re-render. To fix it, I need to call `preventDefault`.

```
  const onSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

Every problem is a bit different, the above is only one example. Try to think about what your test actually does in the real site.

Answer (score 1):

Official docs suggest that the cypress.on method is placed in "cypress/suport/e2e.js"

Docs  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file

CMD + F "Support File"

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false prevents Cypress from failing the test
  if (err.message.includes('Navigation cancelled from')) {
    console.log(' TO INFINITY AND BEYOND ')
    return false
  }
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Add these lines Before your `Test Suit`.

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
// returning false here prevents Cypress from
// failing the test
return false
});
```

Comment: As per the documentation, this answer "turn[s] off all uncaught exception handling". Yet OP, es specifically asking for turning it off on a single cypress test.