# Cypress-Xpath: Correct Xpath syntax for id? It can't find it

Tags: xpath, input, automated-tests, cypress

Tried  cy.get(#Username) , doesn't work- cypress says it can't find it. could it be related to uppercase letter?

Installed Xpath plugin and used this
cy.xpath('//input[@id="Username"]') but it didn't work.

`<input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-gd="identity-login-local-form-username" autofocus="" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" value="">`

[image]

Please before giving -1 , please explain what I need to improve. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with lowercase? Please inspect the page (right-click the `input` + inspect option) and post the HTML for your element.

Comment: @Fody , I did but still no go. Why -1?

Comment: @Fody I updated the question, is that what you were asking to post?

Comment: Someone is trying to close your question, but it seems ok to me. I'm not sure why the capital letter is causing a problem. Try using the `data-gd` attribute instead.

Comment: @MitraA Can you add a screenshot of your HTML showing some levels above the username field.

Comment: @Alapan Das, I just added the HTML ^^, thanks!

Comment: @Mitra A Based on your html `cy.get('#Username').type('some-text')` should work.

Comment: Good to see you found a resolution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried suggestions and people's confirmation that my xpath was correct, I shifted my focus on the error I got while Cypress was trying to find the element. The error I got was uncaught [image]exception.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845493/cypress-uncaught-assertion-error-despite-cy-onuncaughtexception

Answer (score 3):

After downloading xpath plugin, did you add `require('cypress-xpath')` in your project's cypress/support/index.js file?

According to your example, code below should find the `Username`

```
cy.xpath('//input[@id="Username"]')
cy.get('#Username')
```

Comment: In 2022, Cypress Ver-Ver- 10.9.0, code snippet- require('cypress-xpath') will go to file e2e.js in the support folder as folder hierarchy has been changed in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

The capital letter may be causing the problem. Usually ids have a small letter.

Try using the `data-gd` attribute instead.

```js
cy.get('[data-gy="identity-login-local-form-username"]')
```

If that does not work, you may have some shadow DOM before the `<input>` that blocks the search, in which case you can search inside the shadow like this

```js
it('tests the input', {includeShadowDom:true}, () => {
  cy.get('[data-gy="identity-login-local-form-username"]')
})
```

---

I tested with a capital letter `cy.get('#Username')` and `cy.xpath('//input[@id="Username"]')` - both worked for me, so likely there is shadow DOM or an `<iframe>` on your page.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and testing it on your end. Now that I also tested your suggestion to rule out some possibilitiesm I am suspecting the root cause is something outside of getting element.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the page has a default namespace? If the page is served as XHTML, it may have a default XML namespace, in which case the input's name is not simply `input`.

If that is the problem, then you could declare the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace and associate it with a prefix, e.g. `xhtml` (I don't know cypress so not sure how you'd do that), and then query for `//xhtml:input[@id="Username"]`. An alternative is to query for an element whose local name is `input` in any namespace at all, e.g. `//*[local-name()='input'][@id="Username"]`

Answer (score 0):

**In case your username field is under a shadow DOM** which means other fields will also be under the shadow Dom, it would be advisable to write `includeShadowDom: true` in your cypress config file to avoid repetition(`cypress.json` if cypress version < 10; `cypress.config.js` if cypress version > 10), then directly use the command:

```js
cy.get('#Username').type('username-text')
```

**In case your username field is under an iframe**, you can get the [cypress iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin

- To install `npm install -D cypress-iframe`
- Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` file, add the following:

```js
import 'cypress-iframe';
// or
require('cypress-iframe');
```

- In your test write:

```js
cy.iframe('#my-frame')
  .find('#Username')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('username-text')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm the way you are selecting the `Username` input element is correct.

**If you suspect shadow DOM** is interfering with your test, the best way to debug IMO is to

- inspect your DOM around the `<input>`
- look for a parent element that has `#shadow-root` below it (in bold)
- change the test to include this parent
- add the `.shadow()` command after the parent to break through the barrier

```js
cy.get('parent-with-shadow-root')
  .shadow()
  .find('#Username')
```

This debugs and confirms your issue. Everything else, e.g setting global config etc can be done after you know what you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context. A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

Using `ngRoute` In AngularJS `1.2.0` and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to `1.2.x` or later, be sure that you've installed `ngRoute`.