# "ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications" causing Cypress to crash in Edge only

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, cypress, resize-observer

I'm running Cypress to test my Vue 3 app. When running Cypress tests in Edge, I intermittently get the the error `ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.`, which because it's uncaught is stopping the tests from running correctly. Sometimes a test will pass, other times it won't. If I run the full test suite of > 100 tests, the error is guaranteed to turn up at least once. No attempts to [catch and ignore the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845493/cypress-uncaught-assertion-error-despite-cy-onuncaughtexception) have worked, either in the support file or in the actual specs.

This is especially infuriating because:

- `ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.` is an
  error deemed so unimportant that [Chrome and Firefox suppress it by
  default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238740/how-to-ignore-the-resizeobserver-loop-limit-exceeded-in-testcafe), so my tests in those browsers work fine (but I have to support Edge).
- I'm not using a ResizeObserver anywhere in my code.

I've tried temporarily uninstalling any vendor code that uses ResizeObserver to see if that made a difference (it didn't). The only one I wasn't able to uninstall was rollup as Vue 3 uses that to build.

[Another question suggests it could be an extension causing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187282/react-resizeobserver-loop-completed-with-undelivered-notifications/76190200#76190200), but I have no extensions installed in Edge.

Can anyone help me out of this nightmare?

Comment: Please see [Cypress wait for transition to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67748232/22438867) for a mod to add `window.requestAnimationFrame`, if that's possible in your app.

Comment: @AladinSpaz That would only work if I was actually calling a ResizeObserver in my code, which I'm not, unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "if that's possible". But try modding `window.ResizeObserver` in Vue `main.js` or similar top level - not sure what is the entry point for Vue these days.

Comment: If you have a repo, I will have a look.

Comment: @AladinSpaz - Tried putting it in main.js, afraid that didn't work, still getting the same error. (I guess because it's not being called by my app but from somewhere else?)

Comment: (And the project is commercial and confidential so I'm afraid I can't share)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had this error when i was pressing a vuetify v-select to show the options and the width op the options was wider than that of the dialog in which the v-select was located in.
adding `:list-props="{maxWidth:'250px'}` to my v-select solved the issues for me.